# Rollback transaction in SQLyog

Tags: mysql

I use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) as a client against MYSQL.

I would like to execute an SQL script an optionally commit or rollback (as with the client SQLDeveloper). How can I do that with SQLyog? I've searched the web and the help, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a DB Session with `START TRANSACTION`, everything will be controlled via MVCC and you would have to execute `COMMIT`. If the DB Connection terminates (voluntarily or involuntarily), everything will rollback.

You could also `SET autocommit = 0;` to disable it for your session.

Please make sure all involved tables are InnoDB

If any tables involved in UPDATE joins and DELETE joins involve a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM, changes to the MyISAM table will not rollback since it does not support ACID-compliant transactions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transactions-with-different-apis.html) article every client connect to mysql with enabled autocommit.

You can disabled it and work with rollback like in SQLdeveloper. But in contrast to the SQLdeveloper you need to execute commit statements manually.